# Problems with Doctrine 2 Query Builder

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to build a query with Doctrine 2

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                  ->select('*')
                  ->from('Countries','c')
                  //getDQL
                  ->getQuery();

  echo "<pre>";
echo ($qb->execute());
echo "</pre>";
die;
```

for some reason I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message '[Syntax Error] line 0,
>   col 7: Error: Expected
>   IdentificationVariable |
>   StateFieldPathExpression |
>   AggregateExpression | "(" Subselect
>   ")" | ScalarExpression, got '*'' in
>   /home/dodo/doctrine-orm/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   on line 42

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such a thing as "global wildcard" - you should use `c.*`.

Answer (score 19):

`select('c.*')` didn't work for me,  `select('c')` was enough